# A property is "Unable to cast type..." after deserialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I have an object of type `CalculationModel` which I serialize like below:

```
GenerateTextFileNoBend(path, modelNoBend); // from Main()

private static void GenerateTextFileNoBend(string path, CalculationModel model)
{
   if (!File.Exists(path)) {
      using (var file = File.CreateText(path + "noBend.txt")) {
         var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented);
         file.Write(json);
      }
   }
}
```

Afterwards, I deserialize it and compare its properties with the previous object(`modelNoBend`).

```
var jsonText = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\5113\noBend.txt");
CalculationModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CalculationModel>(jsonText);
```

The idea is that, when debugging, after accessing `model`'s property `Element`, it says

> Message = "Unable to cast object of type 'Connectivity.DataModel.Longs.Element' to type 'Calculations.Common.Models.Element'."

The types are probably irrelevant at this point. The idea, however, is that the original `modelNoBend` has the `Element` property fully functional, but after serialization and deserialization, that property is not usable anymore.

What could be the causes?

It is probably worth noting that I am sorry for not providing a fully reproductible code, but I would be extremely glad if you could provide me with some help at least concept-wise on what could be happening.

**EDIT based on @Nsevens**

I changed the code like below when serializing:

```
  private static void GenerateTextFileNoBend(string path, CalculationModel model)
  {
     if (!File.Exists(path)) {
        using (var file = File.CreateText(path + "noBend.txt")) {
           var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings {
              TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
           });
           file.Write(json);
        }
     }
  }
```

And when deserializing:

```
CalculationModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CalculationModel>(jsonText, new JsonSerializerSettings {
   TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
});
```

And I am getting the following error on the line right above:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot create and populate list type System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[Connectivity.DataModel.Generics.Connector`1[System.UInt64],Calculations.Common.Models.Connector]. Path 'Elements.$values[0].Connectors.$values', line 10, position 22.'

Comment: does your serializer persist type information? could be the root cause here? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I just updated the post based on your suggestion

Comment: Don't serialize an enumerable, convert it to an array (or list) before serialization

Comment: @Jamiec I did it like this: `CalculationModel[] modelNoBendArray = new CalculationModel[1] {modelNoBend};` and serialized this array. After the deserialization, which now looks like this: `CalculationModel[] model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CalculationModel[]>(jsonText, new JsonSerializerSettings {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
         });` 

I am getting the same error.

Comment: You misunderstood @Jamiec's comment. Something in you `CalculationModel` is an enumerable (looks like a result of `.Select()`). Replace this value with its `.ToArray()` result. E.g. by adding this line: `model.ThisPropIsTheEnumerableOne = model.ThisPropIsTheEnumerableOne.ToArray();`

Comment: Thanks @cly! If I do it like `model.Elements = model.Elements.ToArray();`, it says that `Property or indexer cannot be assigned to -- it is read only'`. I think that it is worth noting that I do not have access to that Elements thingy. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serialization and deserialization should have been set like this:

`TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects`

Comment: This way the deserialized object contains the values in ˙IEnumerable` `Elements` property?

Comment: Yes, it does, fortunately.